# ionic app cannot connect to php app due to cors

Tags: php, angularjs, ionic-framework, cors

Below is my ionic code. An angular service making an API call.

```
 var login = function (user)
    {
      return $q(function(resolve, reject)
      {
        $http.post(API_ENDPOINT.url + '/login',user)
          .then(function (result)
          {
            if(result.data.success)
            {
              resolve(result.data.msg);
            }
            else
            {
              reject(result.data.msg);
            }
          });
      });
    };
```

This below is the code on the php end.

```
$app    =   new \Slim\Slim();
// Get request headers as associative array
$headers                = $app->request->headers;
$http_origin            = $headers['Origin'];
$allowed_http_origins   = array("http://localhost","http://localhost:80",
    "http://localhost:8080","http://localhost:63342","null",
    "http://localhost:8100","http://localhost:8888","http://localhost:8889");

if (in_array($http_origin, $allowed_http_origins)){  
    $app->response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin',"$http_origin");
}

$app->response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
$app->response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials','true');
$app->response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers','*');
$app->response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin',"$http_origin");


$app->post('/login/', 'Login' );
```

The app is having an issues with the CORS, it gives an error of Access-Control-Allow-Origins not present.

Comment: try changing set of `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to `*`, if that does then it would mean that your `$http_origin` does not contain the correct value

Comment: @entre i tried that already and it did not work

Comment: I found proxy server from Ionic CLI helpful in such cases: http://blog.ionic.io/handling-cors-issues-in-ionic/

Comment: Is is difficult to help without seeing preflight request and your response to it. But what I see, `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *` is invalid. `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` must not contain wildcard, but list of headers. Response to preflight should not contain body, just 2xx response and headers.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem when you test it from `localhost` this is not a problem when you build it to a device.

You could try [THIS](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog) chrome addon to work around CROS.